# Payoff Matrix: Return all as TRUE

Tags: python, function, economics

EDIT:

The problem I posted earlier comes from the fact that I am trying to code an economics experiment. The experiment itself involves a prisoner's dilemma payoff structure but each player is assigned a random number x or y at the outset of each round which gets used in the payoff matrix and thereby controls whether "enter" or "exit" the market.
A link to a detailed structure of the experiment can be found here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G49NU.png

So that is why I am starting with the below code.
But if anyone can think of a better way to design this experiment, I am all ears :)

p.s I am very very new to python; this is my first project.

```
ENTER = "enter"
EXIT = "exit"

def payoff(your_number, your_choice, their_number, their_choice):
    your_pay =
    their_pay = 
    return your_pay, their_pay

print((payoff(3, ENTER, 2, EXIT)) == (3, 0),
payoff(2, EXIT, 4, ENTER) == (0, 3),
payoff(3, ENTER, 3, ENTER) == (1, 1),
payoff(3, EXIT, 4, EXIT) == (0, 0))
```

Comment: Can you clarify the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the `and` keyword which will evaluate to `True` if, and only if, the two conditions it is given are both `True`.

```py
print(
  payoff(3, ENTER, 2, EXIT)) == (3, 0) and
  payoff(2, EXIT, 4, ENTER) == (0, 3) and
  payoff(3, ENTER, 3, ENTER) == (1, 1) and
  payoff(3, EXIT, 4, EXIT) == (0, 0)
)
```

Comment: Sorry, perhaps my original post was not clear. I am trying to augment the code so that will return all true when i Print

Answer (score 0):

Two steps:-
1. change your function return statement to return [your_pay, their_pay]. This will make your function return a list.

2. Then change each comparison to payoff(3, ENTER, 2, EXIT) == [3, 0]